# How to detect if any sound plays on a windows xp machine

Tags: windows, perl, delphi, audio

Is it possible to detect if any sound plays on a windows xp machine?  Help in any language would be useful.  I basically need to write a program that runs all the time and outputs some text to a file whenever a sound plays.  I don't need any specific information about the sound, just whether a sound is playing.  I don't care whether the speakers are actually powered on or anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was easy, but the answer is difficult. You'll need to utilize DirectSound to achieve your purpose. I haven't tested my solution yet, but you can try to call [IDirectSoundBuffer8::GetStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectsoundbuffer8.idirectsoundbuffer8.getstatus%28VS.85%29.aspx), then check the return value of *pdwStatus* parameter. According to MSDN, `DSBSTATUS_PLAYING` is set if the buffer is being heard.

Since you didn't tell about programming language you are using, I implement the following example using my favorite language, Delphi.

```
  var
    dwStatus: DWORD;
    hResult: HRESULT;

  hResult := GetStatus(@dwStatus);
  if hResult = DS_OK then begin
    if dwStatus and DSBSTATUS_PLAYING <> 0 then
      ShowMessage('Sound card is playing sound now.');
  end;
```

#### UPDATE

I just found a VB forum discussed about [how to detect silence](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=371937) (no output of sound card). Download [DetSilence.zip](http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=42865&d=1132602944). In the `DXRecord_GotWavData` Sub, modify the constants `SilencePercent` and `NonSilencePercent` to the values you need.

Comment: @saberworks, I suggest you consider to register at StackOverflow.com because by doing so, many experts might be interested in looking on your problem deeply. Please give a feedback whether the solution works or not.

Comment: Thanks for this, Vantomex.  I went down this path but I think I was doing it wrong because I was only able to get it to give me the status of sounds that I was playing, not of "any sound at all on the card."  I came up with a different solution which I will post in a separate message.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up approaching this in an unconventional manner.  First I installed Virtual Audio Cable (http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm) and configured it as my primary sound device.  I then configured the recording device to record the sound from the primary output device.  This basically means I can hit "record" and it will record anything going to the sound card.  Then I used a perl module, Win32::SoundRec to record sound to a file.  I periodically check the wav file for activity and if there is some, I know sound was playing.  I used another perl module, Audio::Wav, to parse the WAV file and look for activity (silence vs. non-silence).

Comment: thanks for your feedback and your willingness to post the solution that works. BTW, I just found a VB forum discussed about *how to detect silence* (no output of sound card). I have updated my answer to include a link to the forum.