# Reading The System Audio Output Stream

Tags: c#, winapi, audio, .net-4.0, xna

I am currently Making an Oscilloscope Component For XNA and need a bit of help. I would Like to get the Audio Information form The Systems Audio Output Stream, However i am finding it extremely hard to do so. i have found Some Resources but nothing that helps me all the way, or it helps in a way i am not able to grasp. Here are the Following Resources i have found so far.

[How to programmatically get the current audio level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992798/how-to-programmatically-get-the-current-audio-level)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712636

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xnagamestudioexpress/thread/6a3ea3da-849b-475d-a2a4-7cf7c27347d5

As i am not Able to completely get a handle on what to do i have humbly come to you for your help Thank you Vary much.

Comment: This problem is more challenging than it sounds. DirectSound has a lot of nuanced behavior in it. I find there are some good 3rd party solutions that really help abstract this. Are you opened to using free external libraries? I personally recommend BASS.NET, and NAudio is good if you want an entirely managed solution.

Comment: @JacobJ Thanks for the feedback i will look into both of those, and post back with my results.

Comment: JacobJ, would you mind to post your comment as an answer, thus we can treat it as such?

Answer (score 6):

DirectSound has a lot of nuance to it that can make it difficult to work with. If you're open to using some third-party options, there are a few free ones available that abstract the technical details of DirectSound and make this problem much more approachable. I personally recommend BASS.NET - and NAudio is good if you're more interested in an entirely managed solution.

In BASS.NET, your code would look something like this:

```
private RECORDPROC _myRecProc; // make it global, so that the Garbage Collector can not remove it
...
Bass.BASS_RecordInit(-1);
_myRecProc = new RECORDPROC(MyRecording);
// start recording paused
int settings = 0;
int inputSource = 0;
while (settings != -1)
{
  // get the settings of that input
  settings = Bass.BASS_RecordGetInput(inputSource, ref vol);
  if ( Bass.BASS_RecordGetInputName(inputSource) == "What U Hear" ||
       Bass.BASS_RecordGetInputName(inputSource) == "Stereo Mix")
  { 
    break;
  }
  inputSource++;
}    

Bass.BASS_RecordSetInput(inputSource, BASSInput.BASS_INPUT_ON, 0.5F)

int recChannel = Bass.BASS_RecordStart(44100, 2, BASSFlag.BASS_RECORD_PAUSE, 50, _myRecProc, IntPtr.Zero);
...
// really start recording
Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(recChannel, false);
...
// the recording callback
private bool MyRecording(int handle, IntPtr buffer, int length, IntPtr user)
{
  return true;
}
```

Basically, you're initializing BASS. Then you loop through all the possible input sources searching for "What U Hear" or "Stereo Mix." The name of the channel that is a combination of all your speaker output varies from soundcard to soundcard, so you'll have to get a list of the common names. After you've found an appropriate channel, you'll start recording. The MyRecording method will have a buffer for you to analyze.

This is just one way to do it, with one library. Take a look around and see which library provides you with data in a format you want it in.

Comment: heh, was planing in figuring it myself, but thank you so much, ill be positive too add you in the thanks for the project ^_^

Answer (score 0):

XNA includes a MediaPlayer class that gives you access to some "visualization data" (a sampling of frequencies and their volumes). Take a look at [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/22707.aspx) for a tutorial.