# How to speech recognition from video playback?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I currently have an application that can detect my speech based on the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB9lfHDOe5U

In the load event of this form I have the following

```
//Global Variable
SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

            private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //hide border to prevent screen burnout
                this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

                Choices commands = new Choices();
                commands.Add(new string[] { "stock", "news", "percent", "down" }); //need to read company list from db
                GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
                gBuilder.Append(commands);
                Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);


                recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);

                //THIS IS PROBABLY WHERE I NEED HELP-----------
                recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
            }

    //Event called when a word is recognized
    private void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "stock":
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
            break;

            case "news":
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
            break;

            case "percent":
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
            break;

            case "down":
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
            break;
        }
    }

    //Used to enable the recognition to start
    private void btnEnableAudio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
```

I would like to read the audio from the speakers instead of my mic, so if I am playing a video I'd like it to detect those words.

Does anyone have any ideas how to set the input device to the output device?

Comment: try to access the audio output stream and use it as illustrated in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785737/reading-the-system-audio-output-stream

Comment: Unfortunately we can't cough up that much cash for the api. Is there another way, it seems so weird that you can read from the mic but not from the speaker output.

Comment: Whilst BASS.Net now seems to be paid, NAudio is still free and the code library is still available on C#. If you're open to programming languages other than C# lookup VLC https://www.videolan.org/doc/videolan-howto/en/ch09.html. There's also some work on VLC's C# wrapper but does not seem to have an active community around it. please refer https://wiki.videolan.org/C_Sharp/