# C# bass detection from windows audio output

Tags: c#, audio, real-time, visualization

I want to create somewhat of a simple visualizer for my PC audio output channel (same as speakers/headphones) that will send signals to my arduino board when there is bass or treble being played. I already have LEDs wired up and my own program with animations and colors running, I also developed a game modification that lets me control the lights using game events. All I need now is to read my PC audio output channel, find there a specific sound (probably bass, right?) and send byte on serial port just as I did previously.

I can't find any simple tutorials how to read windows audio so I decided to ask here. Where should I start? BASS.NET looks very complicated for that "simple" task. Is there something built-in in standard .NET libraries? I am by no means audio mastermind, I am not even sure if I am using correct terms. In simple words I just want to make lights light up to the rhythm when there is real-time music playing.

Comment: On windows you may be able to find something with directsound API (using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;)

Comment: Here is another link on SO about reading audio (also using BASS.NET): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796571/1108036