# C# - Get Desktop Audio Loudness

Tags: c#, audio

Basically, like in the title, I am trying to find a way to get my Desktop's Audio Playback loudness property and use it for a visualizer of mine. I am planning to do it in a loop as well.

I haven't tried anything, because I have no idea on how to do it. (I don't want to record it, but just get the loudness like OBS Studio does in the Audio Mix's Desktop Audio, or Windows'-Sounds-Playback tab. Also, this may be a duplicate because it feels rather possible that somebody else has already asked something related to this, but I just can't find it.)

Edit:
For people that want to do this, do the following;
Install NAudio using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and define these.

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);
```

and in a loop, run the following

```
var volume = device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue;

var scale = (int)Math.Floor(volume * 100); //can be changed

Console.Write("\r");

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append('-', scale);
sb.Append(' ', 100 - scale); //the integer must be the same as the scale^
Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

the output of the bottom code will be something like this, which will simply be filled with more '-'s as the volume goes higher.
[image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRo8y.png

Note: Tested on .NET 6 alone

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992798/how-to-programmatically-get-the-current-audio-level) and its answers lead you anywhere? [This article](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/displaying-a-volume-meter-using-naudio/) also seems to cover this exact subject quite succinctly.

Comment: @madmonk46 The article actually does, thank you.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an answer so it's clear for anyone else who comes across this, but if you get some code working and want to add your own answer to improve it, feel free to do so

Comment: Done. Once again, thank you.