# How to detect if a System.Media.Sound (BEEP) has been played by another program

Tags: c#, logging, event-handling, beep, system-sounds

I am trying to figure out if a System.Media.Sounds has been played, for error logging purposes.

How would I go about getting a boolean value representing if any of the System.Media.Sounds have been played during the execution of my program?

As I am executing the code, I come across a situation where a system (beeping sound) is played about 10+ times a minute. I would like to make a log for every time the (beeping sound) is played.

Perhaps I can make it an EventArgument?

Comment: I think you have a method that tells to play a sound right? You could add a method below there which counts (a value) into a database if you want to use a database? - if you reach this place -> add +1 to log + time + user + everything you like.

or don't you cause the sound with your code?

Comment: are you the one causing the sound to be played ?

Comment: Is your question about the audio api, or how to build logs? Also as far as I can tell there is no `System.Sound` namespace. Can you please provide more information on how you are producing the beeps? (Source code, documentation links, ect)?

Comment: No, im not causing the sound. The sound is caused by another program and I cannot access that part of its internal code.

Comment: I believe that as a consequence of running my code the "other" program Utilizes System.Media namespace to make a sound. However I do not know that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983463/how-to-detect-if-any-sound-plays-on-a-windows-xp-machine) is similar to yours; unfortunately, the answer that seems to work involves DirectSound, which will probably be a lot more complicated than what you're looking for.